# Can not retrive Source code of a website(getting another source code instead)

Tags: php, android, url, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to retrive source code for [this](https://rarbg.to/torrents.php?category=movies) website but instead I'm getting another source code where it says " Please wait while we try to verify your browser...
If you are stuck on this page disable your browser addons ..."
is there any way around that? 
P.s (I'm runing that on my phone that has no addons)

Code:

```
recTorrentsURl = new URL("https://rarbg.to/torrents.php");
HttpsURLConnection con = null;
con = (HttpsURLConnection) recTorrentsURl.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

is = con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder total= new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while((line= br.readLine())!=null){
            total.append(line).append('\n');

        }
```

Comment: how are you retrieving the source code? please show an example.

Comment: If you're trying to see the PHP, that's not going to happen.  The best you can get is whatever HTML is rendered in your browser.

Comment: You acting like an BOT and the Website checks/verifys your BROWSER.  So try to act like a real User with a real Browser when calling from PHP. But thats hackisch...

Comment: @mister martin here I put in code in the question now (y):

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the website has some for of ddos/script protection(cloudflare i think)

if you can change your "tool" to change the headers then it should be able to bypass this.

for example httrak(tool) you can change your request headers and set a delay to wait x amount of seconds before pulling all the content which will bypass this issue of please wait whilst we verify your browser..

Comment: wow "-2" -was that question so dumb hehe , @iCeptic ty very much look it up at once:) (y)